# vim: how can i make a mapping from a autocmd

Tags: vim, vimrc

in my .vimrc i have an autocmd which cleans up my files, but how can i make a mapping out of the command?

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.test1 silent! :%s/\s\+$//e | silent! :%s/\(\n\n\)\n\+/\1/ | silent! :%s#\($\n\s*\)\+\%$## | :%s/;$
nnoremap ;; silent! :%s/\s\+$//e | silent! :%s/\(\n\n\)\n\+/\1/ | silent! :%s#\($\n\s*\)\+\%$## | :%s/;$<CR>
```

The mapping fails saying

```
Error detected while processing ~/.vimrc:
line  966:
E486: Pattern not found: ;$<CR>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the main problem with your command is that by using `|` you're actually breaking it into several commands, the first of which being `nnoremap`, but from the second on, a series of `silent!` commands with substitutions, which are being run at the time your `.vimrc` is being sourced, rather than becoming part of the command.

Using either `\|` or `<bar>` should solve that.

The second issue is that `nnoremap` expects a command in normal mode, so it takes your `silent!` and runs the `s` (substitute) command, which then replaces the character under the cursor with `ilent! ...`, which is not what you want... You need an extra `:` before that first `silent!` so it knows to go into command mode.

And third, your last command `%s/;$<CR>` is not really well formed, you need two additional `/`s to complete it. I'm assuming your intention is to strip all `;`s at the end of lines, so `%s/;$//` is what I'm assuming you want here. (I also noticed you skipped a `silent!` there, maybe by omission? I'm adding it here, just in case.)

Putting it all together:

```
nnoremap ;; :silent! :%s/\s\+$//e \| silent! :%s/\(\n\n\)\n\+/\1/ \| silent! :%s#\($\n\s*\)\+\%$## \| silent! :%s/;$//<CR>
```

Comment: thx a lot. you got everything right. thx for the explanations too!